# How to access Windows 8 drives from Ubuntu 14?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I am getting this error message when I try to access the Windows drive

[image: hibernation error]

Comment: Read the message: you used hibernation to shutdown windows and it states what you need to do *in windows*. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Windows 8, Windows has been using Fast Startup utility, which is hibernating the system instead of completely shutting down, in order to boot up faster the next time you start your computer. This creates a hibernation file on your disk. When a hibernation file is present, that disk is write protected, this is to prevent your Windows session from getting corrupted the next time it starts. You can solve this either by:

- Executing `sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda5 /mount/point` where mount/point is the location you want to mount the disk. (Note that this mounts the disk in read-only mode, so you can't edit or create anything on the disk. If you want write permission, move to the second option).
- Going into windows, and shutting it down completely. To do this, hold down the Windows key at the bottom right corner of your keyboard next to Ctrl and press R. Type cmd and press Enter. Then type `shutdown -s -t 00` . This will completely shutdown Windows, so when you boot into Ubuntu you won't get that warning.